# Clojure : access declared defrecord in another namespace

Tags: clojure

I am trying to access a "defrecord" from another ns and I get an error.
I am able to access a declared "def" and an declared constructor but not the "defredord".
This is the code:

```
(ns myapp.model)

(defrecord Person [fname lname])

(defn make-person [fname lname]
  (->Person fname lname))

(def p1 (make-person "John" "Doe"))
```

---

```
(ns ibercode.core

(:require [myapp.model :as model]))

;;OK
(def p2 (model/make-person "John" "Doe"))

;;OK
(prn model/p1)

;;clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No 
;;such namespace: ->model, compiling:
(def p3 (->model/Person "John" "Doe"))
```

Thanks
R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood `->`.  It is not syntax, but simply a naming convention.

The name of the constructor function is `->Person`, so qualified, it is `model/->Person`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.